# Trouble reading FAT32 number of hidden sectors

Tags: c++, linux

I attempted to read parts of a FAT32 filesystem on Linux. I struggle reading the number of hidden sectors which should be located at offset 28 (0x1C) and should have a size of 4 bytes. References for this can be found [here](http://www.jessland.net/JISK/Forensics/Areas/Disks_and_Filesystems/FAT.php) and [there](http://www.cse.scu.edu/~tschwarz/coen252_07Fall/Lectures/FAT.html).

The Fat32 file system has been created with [gparted](https://gparted.org/) . When I examine the filesystem with [wxHexEditor](https://www.wxhexeditor.org/) then I see the following values there:

```
OFFSET: 28 29 30 31
VALUE:  00 18 44 10
```

Now I attempted to read the filesystem file with:

```
std::ifstream deviceFile;
char* buffer = new char [4];
deviceFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
deviceFile.ignore(28);
deviceFile.read(buffer, 4);
```

According to the this [wikipedia page the design of FAT32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system) the value should be little endian. Now that I have read the 4 bytes I tried to parse them to an integer like this:

```
int totalNumSectors = (buffer[3] << 24) | (buffer[2] << 16) | (buffer[1] << 8) | (buffer[0]);
```

This however gives me a ridiculous value of 1590288.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should read as 0x10441800, in decimal 272898048. Your value 1590288 is in hex 0x00184410, that is your value read in big-endian.

Comment: Oh yes, I mixed it up. But even then 272898048 as a number for hidden sectors is way above what I would expect.

Comment: Can you add to the question an hex dump of the full boot sector?

Comment: I have just created a partition with gparted to check this value, and I get 0x00000000. My guess is that you are looking at the first sector in the device, not in the partition, so you are seeing MBR or GPT bytes instead of FAT information.